# How Justice of the High Court of Australia officially abbreviated?

Tags: australia

[JSC singular, JSCC plural can officially abbreviate Justice of UK Supreme Court](https://old.reddit.com/r/auslaw/comments/4d3kex/difference_between_j_jj_jja_aj_etc_judge_v_justice/d1ngdm7/) But what for Australia High Court? JHC? HCJ?

Answer (score 1):

### CJ for the Chief Justice, J for any other

From the [Australian Guide to Legal Citation](https://law.unimelb.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0005/3181325/AGLC4-with-Bookmarks-1.pdf) p. 59.

Incidentally, this the same for all courts in Australia, the HCA is identified in the case citation not in the titles of the justices.